# Prevent dragging and dropping from changing cells referencing moved cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm having a problem with my budget spreadsheet. For simplicity's sake, I can recreate the problem as follows.

I have two columns, A with a list of numbers, and B with several cells referencing a block of cells column A. For example:

```
         A           B     
   ----------------------------------------
1. |     6     | =sum(A$1:A$100)          |
2. |     16    | =average(A$1:A$100)      |
3. |     12    |                          |
4. |     10    |                          |
5. |           |                          |
6. |           |                          |
```

My problem is if I drag and drop (or cut and paste) cells A1:A4 and move them to A3:A6 my equations in column B change to match, as such:

```
         A           B     
   ----------------------------------------
1. |           | =sum(A$3:A$103)          |
2. |           | =average(A$3:A$103)      |
3. |     6     |                          |
4. |     16    |                          |
5. |     12    |                          |
6. |     10    |                          |
```

If I use copy/paste the values of column B won't change, but then I run into the problem of the contents of the original A column do change (ie. if the contents of A1 were "=C1" then it would change to "=C3" in the example).

In my actual spreadsheet I'm moving blocks of ledger data down to accommodate new data from my bank. I'm moderately sure this wasn't what was happening a month ago when I last did my budget, or the time before, or the time before.

Comment: Is the row number 100 important, or just "some large number"? If you want to sum everything in column A, use `sum(A:A)` and the problem goes away.

Comment: I changed the spreadsheet to use :A, but the initial $2 is important, and still changes.

Comment: I was trying to say I could still needed to use A$2:A rather than A:A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get round this by using an indirect reference.  For example:

```
=sum(indirect("A$3:A$103"))
```

The reference will then always refer to the specified range even when data is moved through drag and drop or cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a custom script to move the data up and down:

```
function moveBlock(rowStart,colStart,colEnd,direction) {
  // verify direction
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (direction == 0) {
    ui.alert(
     'Error!',
     'You programmed in an invalid direction!',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    return false;
  }

  // grab data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var maxRow = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length;

  // move up or down
  if (direction < 0) {
    // up
    var oVals = sheet.getRange(rowStart-direction,colStart,maxRow-rowStart-direction,colEnd-colStart+1).getValues();
    var cData = sheet.getRange(maxRow,colStart,maxRow-direction,colEnd-colStart+1);
    cData.clear();
    var nData = sheet.getRange(rowStart,colStart,maxRow-rowStart-direction,colEnd-colStart+1);
    nData.setValues(oVals);
  } else {
    // down
    var oVals = sheet.getRange(rowStart,colStart,maxRow-rowStart+1,colEnd-colStart+1).getValues();
    var cData = sheet.getRange(rowStart,colStart,direction,colEnd-colStart+1);  
    cData.clear();
    var nData = sheet.getRange(rowStart+direction,colStart,maxRow-rowStart+1,colEnd-colStart+1);
    nData.setValues(oVals);
  }

  return true;
}
```

I call the script via images in the document that I've assigned scripts to. Since you can't assign a script with parameters, I ended up created several macro-like scripts. For each ledger there are 4 macros: one that moves the data up one row, down one row, up 5 rows, and down five rows. I don't have to pass in the sheet name as the script uses the active sheet.

```
// macros/shortcuts for the various sheets that use moveblock:
function moveUp_Ledger_CC() { return moveBlock(2,1,6,-1); }
function moveDown_Ledger_CC() { return moveBlock(2,1,6,1); }
function moveUp_Ledger_CC_5() { return moveBlock(2,1,6,-5); }
function moveDown_Ledger_CC_5() { return moveBlock(2,1,6,5); }
function moveUp_Ledger_MACU() { return moveBlock(2,1,8,-1); }
function moveDown_Ledger_MACU() { return moveBlock(2,1,8,1); }
function moveUp_Ledger_MACU_5() { return moveBlock(2,1,8,-5); }
function moveDown_Ledger_MACU_5() { return moveBlock(2,1,8,5); }
```