# Cut Cells Without Changing Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have rows where I need to sometimes cut and paste them into a different part of the sheet. However, there is a sum formula that sums the values in the original part. When I cut the row, the sum formula changes because that row was moved.

Is there a way to prevent the sum formula from changing when I cut the row?

Sum Formula: `= SUM($A$1:A$10)`
When I cut row `A1` and place in below row `12`, the sum formula changes to `= SUM($A$2:A$10)`

Comment: Related: [Prevent dragging and dropping from changing cells referencing moved cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102214/88163)

Answer (score 1):

indirect() uses a static string to provide a reference to a range. it will not be modified by any of the features that assist in updating formulas when the sheet structure changes. It will solve this problem but it might be the source of others later. (insert Spiderman quote)

```
=sum(INDIRECT("a1:a10"))
```

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en

not that that explains this use of it well.